# Passing instance variable from controller to view in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a user profile controller called "userinfo" and it's corresponding view. The userinfo index is the root path. In the homepage(which is the userinfo index), I have a link that takes you to the user profile page. It is giving me this error when I click on the image on the view page:[image]
My routes are:[image]
My userinfos_controller:

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_userinfo, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @userinfors = Userinfo.where(:userinfo_id => @userinformation_user_id)
    end

    def show
        @myvideo = Video.last
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = current_user.userinfos.build(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
        @userinformation.destroy
        redirect_to userinfo_path
    end

    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major)
        end

        def find_userinfo
            @userinformation = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

and my view is:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("student.png", class: 'right'), userinfo_path(@userinfors) %>
```

I thought maybe I must include ':index' in the 'before_action :find_userinfo' at the top of my controller. If I do that, the homepage doesn't even load and it gives me this error:[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

## controller

```
def index
  @userinfors = Userinfo.where(:userinfo_id => @userinformation_user_id) #pass id instead of object @userinformation_user_id
end
```

## view

```
<% @userinfors.each do |u| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag("student.png", class: 'right'), userinfo_path(u) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hey man, did you change anything in the controller? Also, should I add ':index' to the "before_action" in the controller?

Comment: @Dinukaperera you have to pass id instead of instace variable userinformation_user_id

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're trying to do perform a lookup based on something that's not an ActiveRecord (database) attribute.

Your root goes to `UserinfosController` which expects `@userinformation_user_id` but I can't tell from your code where that comes from.

Comment: Hey buddy, which part are you confused about? Thanks for trying to help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define your route in order that this will be expecting for an specific param, maybe the user `id`, and then you're able to add the value within your view, in a `link_to` helper:

You could modify your `routes.rb` to expect an `id` as param:

```
get '/user_infors/:id', to: 'userinfos#index', as: 'userinfo_path'
```

Then in your controller, use a `find` to "find" in the database the user with such id. If you'd like to use `where` then that would give you a relationship with all the `userinfos` with the `id` being passed as param.
If you want so, then use `Userinfo.where('userinfo_id = ?', params[:id])`:

```
def index
  @userinfors = Userinfo.find(params[:id])
end
```

And then in your view you can access to `@userinfors`:

```
<% @userinfors.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to image_tag 'student.png', class: 'right', userinfo_path(user) %>
<% end %>
```

I think you could define the `index` to get all the `userinfors` and a `show` method to get an specific one, as you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please help me understand your last line? "a show method to get a specific one"? How do I do that? also, do I have to add ":index" to the before_action in the controller?

Comment: And in the routes, why is it  '/user_infors/:id'? Where is the "user_infors" coming from?

Comment: I mean, if you're trying to find some record, and to "show" it, it's just one record, that could be performed with a show method, in the other hand if you want to show all the records you could use an index method. `/user_infors` would be your index route, `/user_infors/:id` would be to get an specific record.